# Problemas con VSCode

Tags: vscode

últimamente se me viene presentando un problema con el vscode, al intentar abrirlo se pone lento al punto de la pc sugerir que lo cierre, intenté reinstalar, elimine las extensiones y aún nada. Ha alguno de uds le ha pasado antes?

Comment: No, no me ha pasado antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi caso, vi que la mayoría de las extensiones comienzan a comunicarse, y si te fijás en el administrador de tareas, el VSCode llama un montón de recursos. Lo que hice para evitar el exceso de tráfico de banda y uso de CPU, es entrar a la configuración de las extensiones en VSC (es un archivo JSon.config), y comenzá a deshabilitar las opciones de telemetría de las ext, y los envíos de registros, experiencia de usuario y funciones beta. Hacelo gradualmente, y chequeá que no se deshabiliten los módulos que usás. También tuve que desinstalar dos ext: Ninite porque si bien es altamente predictiva, genera un tráfico exhorbitante, en la PC como si utilizaras un servidor y Copilot Gihub, porque genera también mucho tráfico, es engañosa, sus opciones útiles son la mayoría pagas, y genera un bucle de loggeo con Gihub bastante molesto, que me clavó el VSC varias veces. Espero haberte podido ayudar en algo.